# JAXB generates unformatted XML using XMLEventWriter

Tags: java, jaxb, formatted

I'm using JAXB in order to generate XML files, and due to a business need I'm currently writing it to the middle of some other XML file using XMLEventWriter:

```
marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, xmlEventWriter);
```

And currently setting some properties like:

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "utf-8");
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
```

But, besides having the **JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT** set to **true**, my **XML is not being formatted**.

Does anyone knows what may be the problem?
This only happens when I use the XMLEventWriter...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Strange... It usually works. Is there a chance that you are creating Unix EOL symbols and then viewing the file using Notepad on windows?

Comment: Posting a minimal example that reproduces the problem would go a long way.

Answer (score 3):

When you are using an `XMLEventWriter` as a sink, the JAXB marshaller is only in charge of sending the appropriate XML events to it and the `XMLEventWriter` may still choose to write out unformatted XML. My advice is to check the configuration of your `XMLEventWriter` in addition to `Marshaller`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the default `XmlEventWriter` implementation does not indent. The [stax-utils](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22net.java.dev.stax-utils%22%20AND%20a%3a%22stax-utils%22) library provides a `IndentingXMLEventWriter` which might help in these cases.